# How to combine letters from a string and save them into other variables in JAVA, Android

Tags: java, android, string, save

I hope that this is not a stupid question, as this is only my 5th week into JAVA and Android programming. So I'm still very new to this.

Here's my code:

```
public void splitData(){ //**********************PROBLEM HERE**********************

    //Initialise everything to 0 to prepare for variable entry
    y=0;
    gender = "";
    sAge = "";
    sTotalC = "";
    smoker = "";
    sHDLC = "";
    medication = "";
    sSystolic = "";

    //To locate the spaces in the data
    for(x=0;x<toSplit.length();x++){

        if (toSplit.charAt(x) == ' '){

            spaceCount[y]=x;
            y++;

        }

    }

    //to put together gender
    for(x=0;x<spaceCount[0];x++){

        gender+= toSplit.charAt(x);

    }

    //to put together age
    for(x=spaceCount[0]+1;x<spaceCount[1];x++){

        sAge+=toSplit.charAt(x);

    }

    //to put together total Cholesterol
    for(x=spaceCount[1]+1;x<spaceCount[2];x++){

        sTotalC+=toSplit.charAt(x);

    }

    //to put together smoker status
    for(x=spaceCount[2]+1;x<spaceCount[3];x++){

        smoker+=toSplit.charAt(x);

    }

    //to put together HDL Cholesterol level
    for(x=spaceCount[3]+1;x<spaceCount[4];x++){

        sHDLC+=toSplit.charAt(x);

    }

    //to put together medication status
    for(x=spaceCount[4]+1;x<spaceCount[5];x++){

        medication+=toSplit.charAt(x);

    }

    //to put together Systolic BP
    for(x=spaceCount[5]+1;x<=toSplit.length();x++){

        sSystolic+=toSplit.charAt(x);

    }



}
```

}

So what is there is basically my terrible attempt find all the spaces in a string, and based on the spaces, combine alphabets together from the string into different variables and display each individual new constructed words into an EditText.

Everything in this code fine, right up till i hit the button mSplit should begin to do said task and then it'll show an "Unfortunately the app has stopped working".

I have googled and poked my nose around many websites but most of them use other forms of methods to split their sentences and immediately display it, without saving it into another array or variables.

It would seem and i know that i'm probably doing it the long and stupid way as i have limited knowledge about C++ thus the reason why i attempted to do it the only way i know how.

I am open to all suggestions and comments and i thank you humbly in advance.

Comment: will you provide exception logs from Logcat

Comment: Do you mean this ? "This is string" then store them as... a="This", b="is", c="string"

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for taking the time.

Prateek, i have no idea what an Exception log is, but I've edited the post and i hope that it is that.

Kettu, yes indeed, that it what i wish to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the split function then put it into an string array

```
String what = "word word1 word2 word3";
String [] temp = what.split(" ");
```

temp[0] will contain "word"
temp[1] will contain "word1"
and so on...

Comment: Now to understand it, is it safe to say that the spacing in what.split(" "); will split everything by only taking values between spaces? And if so, will putting a hyphen, for example, what.split("-") split everything between hyphens?

Comment: yes it is, so if the string example are "word1-word2" then the split will produce word1 and word2, and the hyphen will be discarded

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
String[] infoArray = info.split("\\s+");
```

Do the same thing for your address.
In this way you don't have to initialize your array before you know it's size and you can ignore all white spaces too. It's better to `trim` your string before splitting it.

Answer (score 0):

if you know how many of them and have more than one space in between...

```
    String toSplit = "aoksd    oaskod    ssdoks    aoskdo    skasdk soakd";
    String[] msg = new String[6];
    int a = 0;
    int c = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        a = toSplit.indexOf(" ");
        if(a == -1)
        {
            msg[c] = toSplit;
            break;
        }
        msg[c++] = toSplit.substring(0, a);
        toSplit = toSplit.substring(a, toSplit.length()).trim();
    }
```